# What's the difference between RESTful web service and one that isnt?

Tags: rest, http

I've read and seen many videos about REST but I still don't get whats the difference between using REST and just working with http requests.

Answer (score 2):

A ReSTful web service is a web service that satisfies the constraints set out in [Roy Fielding's PhD Disseration *Architectural Styles and the Design of Network-based Software Architectures*](https://www.ics.uci.edu/~fielding/pubs/dissertation/top.htm). If it doesn't, then it's not ReSTful.